# HTML forms hide text value when in focus - Without any JavaScript

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple form which is like this:

**The HTML:**

```
<form action="post">
    <input class="text" type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name"/>
    <br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name" />
    <br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="username" value="Username" />
    <br />
    <input class="text" type="password" name="password" value="password" />
    <br />
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
</form>
```

**The CSS:**

```
fieldset { margin:1em 0; }
form { margin:0; }
input { }
input.text { color: #aaa; }
input:focus { background:#ddd; }
input, select, textarea { display:block; margin-bottom:5px; padding:5px 10px; }
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] { padding: 0; display:inline; vertical-align:-1px; }
input[type="submit"] { cursor:pointer; }
label { font-weight:normal; display:block; margin-top:0.5em; }
```

**The Output:**

[image]

**What I want is.....**

When a visitor clicks in the input field and the `background-color` changes to `#ddd` *(whch I am achieving by using css `input:focus { background:#ddd; }`)*, Can the text like 'Last Name' **be hidden**. Can I use some css like `display:none` or something else.

If yes, how? Kindly help.

**Please note:** I do not want to use any JavScript if possible.

Comment: Use the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute (but it's not supported in older browsers, so it's a good idea to use a [JavaScript polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) too).

Comment: Don't use `placeholder` (which is for hints and examples, not labels) or `value` (which is for default values (e.g. the value you tried last time, today's date or your location based on GeoIP). Use separate `<label>` elements and keep them visible so the user knows what they are supposed to be entering in the field they are working in. Disappearing labels are a horrible UI anti-feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In html 5 you can use placeholder lik this:

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name"/>
```

And for older browser i use this jquery script

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
  $("input[type=text], textarea").each(function() {
    return $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder")).addClass("placeholder");
  }).bind("focus", function() {
    if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
      return $(this).val("").removeClass("placeholder");
    }
  }).bind("blur", function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
      return $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder")).addClass("placeholder");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) for a more comprehensive polyfill, seeing as your example will only cover IE.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you hide the value as you discuss in your question, you'll remove the ability to see any value that has been input.

You'll either need to use the `placeholder` attribute (form of `placeholder="Some text"`) or javascript. Support for the `placeholder` attribute isn't brilliant: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder.

Or even better, you could use `placeholder` and include a polyfill that addresses any browsers without support: https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill